# Error when adding libraries on Android Studio

Tags: android, thrift, tango

I'm trying to create an app for android (google Tango) that uses thrift to send some information to a client. I take a sample Tango app which runs without Thrift. Then when I add try to add some of the Thrift dependencies (like slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar) I suddenly get errors like

> error: package com.google.atap.tangoservice does not exist

I don't get what's wrong, it worked before...
Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Thank you

---

UPDATE

The way I added the library was by clicking right on App>new>module then I chose import jar, and selected the jar. Then I went to project structure and in dependencies I added the module of the jar I imported.

Adding it like this did not help me resolve the conflicts I had before:

import org.slf4j.Logger;

giving me the error "cannot resolve symbol 'Logger'".
And it also introduced the errors previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a dependency to your build.gradle file like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.atap.tangoservice'
}
```

Comment: Adding the line you mention didn't fix the problem. It still tells me : "cannot resolve symbol 'atap'"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using local jar dependency then add it like this to the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/something_local.jar')
}
```

Comment: I don't have a files folder, the way I added the library was by clicking right on App>new>module then I chose import jar, and selected the jar. Then I go to project structure and in dependencies I added the module of the jar I imported. Would I still neeed to do what you say?

Comment: you should put the .jar to the libs folder in your project (Yourproject/app/libs/), then use the dependency what i wrote.

Comment: I've seen a video where this is done, but i don't have the create directory option. I have a "new> android resource directory" option. Is this equivalent? If so, what should the resource type be? Thanks

Comment: Just navigate to the project folder in your operating system, then there create the "libs" folder in the "app" folder.

Comment: I get the error: Gradle DSL not found: 'compile()'. Possible causes: The project 'QuickstartJava' may be using a version of the android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method, etc. There is a comment in the gradle file that says: "Note: do not place your application dependencies here; they belong in the individual module build.gradle files"

Comment: put the dependencies in the app's build.gradle